# Is there a way to generate a mapping graph like this?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am wondering whether there are any functions in Mathematica that can generate mapping graphs like the one shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
 Graph[{"A", "B", "C", 1, 2, 3}, {"A" -> 1, "A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 1}, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexStyle -> ColorData[97][1], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, FontSize -> Large], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[{{1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}]]
```

[image]